# After creating table synonym, how to get original table name from synonym?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server 2016 Express. I create synonym below.

```
CREATE SYNONYM Mytable
  FOR [mydatabase].[dbo].[MyOriginalTable];
```

And I change that synonym once or more in a year, like below.

```
DROP SYNONYM Mytable;

CREATE SYNONYM Mytable
  FOR [mydatabase].[dbo].[MyOriginalTableOther];
```

Can I recognize that current synonym "MyTable" is referring which one ?

Comment: check this `select base_object_name 
from sys.synonyms 
where name = 'Mytable'`

Comment: Great work, Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

*Use this-*

```sql
SELECT base_object_name FROM SYS.SYNONYMS WHERE NAME = 'synonym_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

For PL/SQL, it worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.SYNONYMS WHERE SNAME = 'SYNONYM_NAME';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35823476)